# OSX - commands in terminal returning command not found

Tags: mac, bash, command-line, terminal

I recently downloaded and installed scala(tried to anyway) and just noticed that commands in terminal are not found.. I was tinkering with my path variable so I assume that is the problem...

I was reading around and saw that all of those commands should be in /usr/bin directory.. so if i type /usr/bin/ls into terminal i should still get a list.  But I can't seem to find any of those commands (ls, mv, cp, etc).. they are just nowhere to be found

Does anybody know how to fix this?  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not a fix, but most of those commands are found in [`/bin`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#BINESSENTIALUSERCOMMANDBINARIES), not `/usr/bin`.

Comment: All of the three are.

Answer (score 1):

`ls` is in `/bin`

you need to modify the `PATH` environment variable to include the bin directory of your scala install.

for example, to add all the android sdk commands to my path, i put

`export PATH=${PATH}:~/sdks/android-sdk-mac_86/tools`

in my `~/.bash_profile`

Be very careful when modifying the path.  If you do it wrong, you will lose access to a lot of the system commands.

Answer (score 1):

Put `/bin` in your path by running this command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/bin
```

All these binaries exist in `/bin` under Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

if you add additional packages to your mac, there are some locations, which make the most sense, so that all users can use them.

These are `/opt` and `/usr/local`

I prefer `/opt` as does for example MacPorts.

So, to install Scala do the following

- Download Scala and unpack
- sudo mkdir -p /opt/scala
- sudo chown -R YOUR_USERNAME `/opt/scala`
- move contents from unpacked folder to `/opt/scala`, so that the structure will have a `/opt/scala/bin` folder

Now you have installed Scala. Next, you have to edit your PATH accordingly so that you can call the files in /opt/scala/bin from everywhere:

- Edit ~/.profile and add these lines

  export SCALA_HOME=/opt/scala

  export PATH=${SCALA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}

Now either close all Terminal windows and reopen them
or
in the window you have still open do a 
`source ~/.profile`

When you restart your Mac, your .profile will automatically be sourced. So the third option would be just to restart your Mac. :-)

Greetings,

Jan